# GLMERTREE Nested Random effect

Tags: lme4-nlme, cart, party

Is it possible to include a nested random effect in a formula of glmertree? 
(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmertree/glmertree.pdf)

I tried it, but it does not seem to work:  (R2 should be nested in R1)

```
gt <- glmertree(A01 ~  V1 + V3  |R1/R2 , family="binomial", data = data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
glmertree(y ~ x1 + x2 | id | z1 + z2 + z3)
```

means:

- `x1` and `x2` are fixed regressors whose effects are to be estimated in each leaf of the tree.
- `id` is a cluster variable for which a random intercept `(1 | id)` is included.
- `z1`, `z2`, and `z3` are the partitioning variables for growing the tree.

Equivalently to the formula above you can also write:

```
glmertree(y ~ x1 + x2 | (1 | id) | z1 + z2 + z3)
```

and you can also include more complicated terms in the random effects part such as

```
glmertree(y ~ x1 + x2 | (1 | id1/id2) | z1 + z2 + z3)
```

etc.